Brave/Chrome: Selectively turn on accelerations
chrome://gpu shows what kind of accelerations the browser uses.
I can disable them all by disabling Use graphics acceleration when available in Settings.
Can I turn them off individually?
Background for why I want to do that: Laptop sometimes hard reboots when scrolling in Twitter

Some (if not all) should be available in chrome://flags/

There is also chrome://about which lists all the available urls, for example you could use chrome://feedback/ to tell google's AI you are having problems.
